# Python – rTorrent - XMLRPC library – get tracker url

Tags: python

I am using „XMLRPC library“ to get info from rTorrent server.

```
server = xmlrpc.client.Server(server_url) 
name=server.get_name()
tracker = server.t.get_url(torrent,0)
```

This works fine. I get name and first tracker url.

But, how to get tracker name by using multicall2?

This works:

```
print(server.d.multicall2("", "main","d.hash=", "d.get_name=", "d.get_size_bytes=","d.get_ratio=","d.state="))
```

It show all torerent like

```
['717BD92A209D56B3E89422B903BAC209E1114C55', 'Mastering_Visual_Studio_2019,_2nd_Edition_by_Kunal_Chowdhury.epub', 12115165, 0, 1]
```

When I add "t.get_url=" param to multicall2

```
print(server.d.multicall2("", "main","d.hash=", "d.get_name=", "d.get_size_bytes=","d.get_ratio=","d.state=", "t.get_url="))
```

I got

```
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -503: 'Target of wrong type to command.'
```

When I add " "t.multicall=" param to multicall2

I got this result

```
['717BD92A209D56B3E89422B903BAC209E1114C55', 'Mastering_Visual_Studio_2019,_2nd_Edition_by_Kunal_Chowdhury.epub', 12115165, 0, 1, [[]]]
```

How to pass t.get_url param to "t.multicall=" inside multicall2?

Is there another way to obtain this information?

Comment: Haven't been able to get this to work either, the best I've found is `tracker_url = server.t.multicall(hash, "", "t.url=")[0][0]`, but not very efficient if you want to do it for every torrent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
torrents = server.d.multicall2("",
  "main",
  "t.multicall=,\"\",\"t.url=\"")

for torrent in torrents:
  print(torrent[0][0][1])
```

Potentially you'll need to use `t.get_url`? I haven't got that command, I'm using a library corresponding to [these](https://rtorrent-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmd-ref.html) docs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's going on here? How is `t.multicall` interpreted in this context? Usually you have to supply a hash to `t.multicall`. Also what is `torrent[0][0][0]` here? The first element in the 2-element tracker array

Answer (score 2):

The `t.get_url` command has been renamed to `t.url` (along with other commands).

https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/rTorrent-0.9-Comprehensive-Command-list-(WIP)